# (Java) How do I use tabs to switch between different icons for a JLabel?

Tags: java, tabs, jlabel

I have a program that has icons in JLabels. I want to be able to switch between different icons for the JLabel by clicking between different tabs. (There would be two images per label, and preferably I'd be able to attach the tabs right above the label). From what I've read, I would want to use a JTabbedPane, but how would I implement it in this way?

Comment: So you have one JLabel & multiple tabs, and you want to change the icon in JLabel when you switch the tab?

Comment: @gohil90 yeah, pretty much, except I don't have the tabs yet due to lack of knowledge about them (and the Oracle documentation is all about switching between panels)

Comment: You need to have a different JPanel associated with each tab. That is how Swing works. If you see the JTabbedPane docs, you have to have different JPanel for different tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I can just use different labels each in its own panel.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18515119)

Comment: @TomJowitt No, one should not edit answers into question, but post them as answers instead. Please review accordingly in the future.